# Pass multiple parameters in Html.BeginForm MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int clubid)
{
  var club = db.Clubs.Single(c=>c.Id == clubid);
  ViewBag.Club = club;
  Competition comp = db.Competitions.Create();
  return View(comp)
}
```

and in my .cshtml:

```
@Model Models.Competition
...
@Using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

This works fine with the following Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Competition comp)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid){...}

  return RedirectToAction(...);

}
```

However, I want to pass an additional parameter from the `@ViewBag.Club` object:

```
[HttpPoSt]
public ActionResult Create(int clubid, Competition comp){...}
```

How do I code this in the `BeginForm`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There are two options here.

1. a hidden field within the form, or
2. Add it to the route values parameter in the begin form method.

**Edit**

```
@Html.Hidden("clubid", ViewBag.Club.id)
```

or

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller",
                       new { clubid = @Viewbag.Club.id }, FormMethod.Post, null)
```

Comment: @Johan is there any big difference between the 2?

Comment: @I meant more along the line of security, performance or anything? is one an old way or a new way?

Answer (score 1):

Another option I like, which can be generalized once I start seeing the code not conform to DRY, is to use one controller that redirects to another controller.

```
public ActionResult ClientIdSearch(int cid)
{
  var action = String.Format("Details/{0}", cid);

  return RedirectToAction(action, "Accounts");
}
```

I find this allows me to apply my logic in one location and re-use it without have to sprinkle JavaScript in the views to handle this. And, as I mentioned I can then refactor for re-use as I see this getting abused.