# ASP.NET MVC BeginForm not able to post with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with a searchbox on it.  When someone types something into the search box and hits the search button I am trying ot do a post to capture the search filter and then fire off a view.

Here is the controller code

```
public class SpotsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SearchSpots(string searchfilter)
    {
        //your code here....
        return Index(searchfilter);
    }
```

Here is the code from my view up until the part that is tryign to do the submit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Haunt Spotter</title>
</head>
<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post"><@Html.AntiForgeryToken()></form>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchSpots", "Spots"))
            {
                <input id="searchfilter" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="searchfilter">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I take the parameter off of the controller function it works fine.  If not it seems to crash and try to re display a get which fails because I only have a post function for this.  I am guessing I have something screwed up with the parameter but I can't figure out what it is.  Any help woudl be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Based on feedback I have changed my post to a get

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SearchSpots(string searchfilter)
    {
        //your code here....
        return Index(searchfilter);
    }
```

and my view code to this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchSpots", "Spots", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
    <input id="searchfilter" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="searchfilter">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
}
```

Unfortunately I still have the original issue.  If I remove the searchfileter parameter from my controller call then it goes into the call with no problems but when I am expecting the modelbinder to give me a searchfilter it crashes out.

Here is the call I am redirecting to in my search function

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Spots
    public ActionResult Index(string filter = "")
    {
        ViewBag.initialFilter = filter;
        if (User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin"))
        {
            return View(db.Spots.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Spots.Where(x => x.Approved).ToList());
        }

    }
```

and the view that is displayed

```
@model IEnumerable<HauntSpots.Models.Spot>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2 class="align-right">Haunt Spots</h2>

@if (Context.User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin"))
{ 
    <p style="padding-top:20px">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Create")" title="Add New Spot" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Add New</a>
    </p>
}

<table id="dt-spots" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        @if (Context.User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin"))
        {
            <th></th>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
{

        <tr>
            <td>
                @if (Context.User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin"))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden(Url.Action("Edit", "Spots", new { id = item.Id }))
                    <a style="color: Red; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 2em" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Spots", new { id = item.Id })" title="Delete Spot" class="btn"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></a>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.Hidden(Url.Action("Details", "Spots", new { id = item.Id }))
                }
            </td>
            <td>

                @if (item.Image == null)
                {
                    <img width="100" height="100"
                         src="~/Content/Images/NoPhoto.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img width="100" height="100"
                         src="@item.Image" class="img-rounded"/>
                }
            </td>
            <td >
                <div class="form-group pull-left col-md-2">
                    <h4>@item.Title </h4>
                    <h5 style="clear: left">
                        @if (item.Address != null)
                        {
                            <span>@item.Address</span>
                            <br/>
                        }

                        @if (item.State == null)
                        {
                            <span>@item.City</span><br/>
                            <span>@item.Country</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (item.State == "")
                            {
                                <span>@item.City</span>
                                <br/>
                                <span>@item.Country</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span>@item.City, @item.State</span>
                                <br/>
                                <span>@item.Country</span>
                            }
                        }
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group pull-left col-md-8">
                    <h6>@item.Summary</h6>
                </div>
            </td>
            @if (Context.User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin"))
            {
                <td>
                    @if (@item.Approved)
                    {
                        <span style="color: green">Approved</span>
                }
                else
                {
                        <span style="color: red">Not Approved</span>
                }
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Initalize and configure DataTables
        $('#dt-spots').dataTable({
            "oSearch": { "sSearch": "@ViewBag.initialFilter" }
        });


        $("tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
            window.location = $(this).find('input').attr('name');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you need a `POST`? You're not doing any inserts or updates, just fetching results based on a parameter (`searchfilter`)—use `GET`.

Comment: Based on some thing I had seen online since the searchfilter is not there when the page was rendered I needed to do a post to get the value to use.  Even if I was able to use a get though this still seems liek an issue with me trying to pass a parameter since the post fires correctly when none are specified

Comment: As an aside you should not normally return a view from a Post action. Google Post Redirect Get

Comment: @DaveWade change `<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>` to `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> />`.. I believe this has something to do with `<button>` HTML not working correctly with forms..

Comment: I did attempt this but got the same error

Comment: @DaveWade Okay, let's start from the beginning.. have you debugged and is the method getting hit?

Comment: I have tested this personally, and it is working for me.  I am starting to believe that this is a routing issue.  Can you post your Route.Config file?

Comment: @DaveWade based on your updated question, your solution seems superfluous - have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In agreement with most of the other answers stating that this needs to be an `HttpGet` request rather than an `HttpPost` request I believe that this can be solved by changing your HTML.

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchSpots", "Spots", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
    <input id="searchfilter" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="searchfilter">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"</i>/>       // part that needs changing
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchSpots(string searchfilter)
{
    // logic       
}
```

I believe your issue can be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-butto).  `<button>` is exactly what it is.. a button.. it basically does nothing, and is mainly used for JS purposes.  However, the `<input type="submit" />` actually **submits** the surrounding form.

I hope this helps!

UPDATE

I did need the input to pass the parameter.  I still had the same error even after it was being passed and I had to make this final tweak to get it running

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SearchSpots(string searchfilter)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { filter = searchfilter}); 
    }
```

I needed to redirect instead of trying to return a view

Comment: I missed the element type in my answer (shameless copy-pasting), will factor that in.

Comment: @trashr0x so you meant to change `<button>` to `<input />`?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying I've added your suggestion to my answer (though I'm not sure it's the problem).

Comment: @trashr0x ahh i see. I haven't heard anything from the OP, so idk.

Comment: This solution was the closest to what I needed.  The input did get me the parameter passed.  I still had the issue and had to change my controller function to do a redirect instead of returning a view.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @DaveWade ahh silly of me.. I didn't even recognize that you were trying to return to the Index view.. If I knew that I could've been a lot more help haha

Comment: @DaveWade Now looking at your code.. do you mean `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { filter= searchfilter}); `?  Your Index action doesn't have a parameter with the name, `searchfilter`.. just `filter`

Comment: lol yes I just figured that out and fixed it 2 minutes ago.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GET` instead of a `POST`—you're not doing any inserts or updates, just fetching results based on a parameter (`searchfilter`). With a `GET`, the values of the input elements in your form will be appended as parameters to the query string of the target URL, which would produce something like `mywebsite.com/spots/spotsearch?searchfilter=whateverValueInTheInputBox` (depending on how you have your routing configured).

Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchSpots", "Spots", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
    <input id="searchfilter" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="searchfilter">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>       
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SpotsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SearchSpots(string searchfilter)
    {
        // ...        
    }
}
```

Edit: As per @BviLLe_Kid, you can try replacing `<button>` with `<input>`.

Edit 2: Can't help but wonder why you are proxying the call to `Index` via `SearchSpots`, causing an unnecessary redirect. If all that `SearchSpots` does is redirect to `Index`, why not submit the form directly to `Index`?

Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Spots", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
    <!-- remember to rename to name="filter" below -->
    <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="filter">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"</i>/>
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: Spots
public ActionResult Index(string filter = "")
{
    ViewBag.initialFilter = filter;
    if (User.IsInRole("SiteAdmin"))
    {
        return View(db.Spots.ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(db.Spots.Where(x => x.Approved).ToList());
    }

}
```

Comment: No luck with the get either although I think you are right and I should be doing a GET instead of a POST.  After I made the changes and it crashed I removed the parameter from the controller action and it goes in just fine so it seems to have something to do with the parameter I am expecting the modelbinder to provide for me.

Comment: why `return Index(searchfilter);`? If you're returning a view for that particular action, just `return View(yourModelHere);` and then in your view add `@model modelType` (if `yourModelHere` is a string for example, you'd write `@model string`).

Comment: Basically index is the view I want it normally opens up and displays an unfiltered list that you can filter with a text box.  I am trying to call this view up which already has a model of the data I am displaying and I just want an initial filter put on the data.  I will post the call and view above

Comment: you have an extra `>` after `"submit"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing `FormMethod.Post` in

`@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchSpots", "Spots", FormMethod.Post))
 {...`

Comment: I did try adding this but with no luck.  I still get the same error which seems to be it choking on the parameter I am expecting in the controller function

Answer (score 0):

you don't need two forms in your HTML and this code is working and post search text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Haunt Spotter</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchSpots", "Spots", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input id="searchfilter" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="searchfilter">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And you can add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in your action

Comment: I made these changes but still get the same error as before basically crashes if i am requiring a parameter in my controller action

Comment: @DaveWade can you share your get method  that display the view ?

Comment: I shared the call that Search gets the view from and the view above

Answer (score 0):

This is a routing issue.  You don't have a route that will hit SearchSpots with a parameter. So either change your route, or change the BeginForm to include the parameter.

[ASP.NET MVC -  passing parameters to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155864/asp-net-mvc-passing-parameters-to-the-controller)

[Pass multiple parameters in Html.BeginForm MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013669/pass-multiple-parameters-in-html-beginform-mvc)