# Search two parameters with Html.BeginForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The application has tabs:
**All, Computers, Telephones**

The product search should depend on the given tab, that is if we browse the phone tab, only the phones should show us when searching.

Classes:

Product:

```
public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set; }
        public decimal Price {get; set; }
        public int CategoryId {get; set; }
```

Category:

```
public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm ("Index", "Product", FormMethod.Get, null))
    {
    div class="input-group"
    input id="search" type="search" class="form-control" name="search" 
    placeholder= "Search ...">
    button class="btn btn-default">Search button>
    div>

    }
```

Comment: @Johan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013690/3635558) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index Action of Product Controller should receive CategoryId also

```
public ActionResult Index(string search, int categoryId)
{
}
```

Form should send categoryId and hidden field

```
@using (Html.BeginForm ("Index", "Product", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
  <input id="search" type="text" name="search">
  <input type="hidden" id="categoryId" value="1" name="search">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>    
}
```

Detect tab change and change categoryId value

Ex: with Jquery

```
$("#categoryId").val(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for answers guys! I did it differently. In the controller, the category that was called from the bookmark I added to ViewModel was sent back to the view. From the object I added to the hidden input. <input type = "hidden" id = "category" **value = "@ Model.CurrentCategory"** name = "category">